# Adding Two different Delegates in iPhone

Tags: iphone, delegates, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to iphone app development. I want to add two different delegates.
I know how to add multiple delegates of same class like 
UIViewController .
I want like this
@interface HelloWorld : CCLayer, UIViewController
in which one class is CCLayer of cocos2d and second one simple UIViewController.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I think you have your terminology mixed up. In "@interface HelloWorld : UIViewController <Delegate1, Delegate2>" - UIViewController is the superclass of HelloWorld. Delegates are then provided in <>s after the superclass. Multiple delegates can be provided separated by commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CCLayer but you can't do multiple inheritance in Obj-C (so you can't have two superclasses). What you can do is create two classes, one that subclasses UIViewController and the other subclasses CCLayer and then create a protocol/delegate pattern to allow communication between the two.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html